# Titanium SDK 5.1.2 - Android 6.0 Permissions

Tags: android, permissions, appcelerator, android-6.0-marshmallow, appcelerator-titanium

Since SDK 5.1.0, the target SDK has to be 23, which makes some of the permissions stop working. I mean, they have to be requested during run time, but Titanium SDK doesn't really provide a way to do so.

I need to read and write to the usb storage and to read the phone state. Is there any workaround? Will the methods to request these permissions be included in future SDK releases?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the appc sample app:

https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/appc-sample-ti510/blob/master/app/controllers/permissions.js

It is an example on how to use the new permissions. At the moment you need to use the camera permission to access external storage. There is already a [jira ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20235) that will separate these permissions

Comment: What about phone state? Titanium should expose methods for all kinds of permissions.

Comment: not sure if there is any method in the sdk that uses this permission. But feel free to add a ticket on jira that this permission is missing. Otherwise if it's a module you are using try to add a feature request at the module-page

Comment: @Shawn The Titanium SDK exposes `requestXPermissions` methods for all permission required by Titanium APIs. If you extend Titanium with custom modules that require other permissions then that module should implement methods to request those permissions.

Comment: Well, right now I have to request Camera Permission for Storage Permission. And there is no method to request permission for Phone State. I need it for Ti.Android.registerBroadcastReceiver(callback, ["android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"]). I don't use any module. I think the problem is the targetSDK has to be 23, but Titanium doesn't expose all the requestXPermissions.

Comment: I mean, maybe Titanium SDK should expose a function like this:
 `@Kroll.method
 public void requestPermission(String permission)
 {
  Activity thisActivity = TiApplication.getInstance().getCurrentActivity();
  
  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,new String[]{permission},0);
  
 }` so that we can request any permission we want.

Answer (score 2):

For now you can also use a special module - https://github.com/gimdongwoo/Ti-Android-RequestStoragePermission

I tested it in my project and it works fine.